# googlemock - Mocking a method that returns a type with multiple user-defined conversions

Tags: c++, googlemock

I’m writing unit tests for a new component and one of the interface methods returns an object that has several user-defined conversions. When mocking such a method, it seems the compiler complains about ambiguity:

```
gdpr1@BEL081089 ~/Code/sandbox/mocking
$ make && ./tests.exe
Scanning dependencies of target tests
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tests.dir/Foo.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tests.dir/FooTest.cpp.o
In file included from /cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:58:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h:46,
                 from /cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:46,
                 from /cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:58,
                 from /home/gdpr1/Code/sandbox/mocking/FooTest.cpp:1:
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h: In instantiation of ‘const bool testing::internal::ImplicitlyConvertible<const Trouble&, long long int>::value’:
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:236:38:   required from ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& testing::internal2::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const T&) [with Char = char; CharTraits = std::char_traits<char>; T = Trouble]’
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:285:7:   required from ‘void testing_internal::DefaultPrintNonContainerTo(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = Trouble; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:476:49:   required from ‘void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo(testing::internal::WrapPrinterType<(testing::internal::DefaultPrinterType)3u>, const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = Trouble; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:511:17:   required from ‘void testing::internal::PrintTo(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = Trouble; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:762:12:   required from ‘static void testing::internal::UniversalPrinter<T>::Print(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = Trouble; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:1385:31:   required from ‘void testing::internal::ActionResultHolder<T>::PrintAsActionResult(std::ostream*) const [with T = Trouble; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
/home/gdpr1/Code/sandbox/mocking/FooTest.cpp:21:1:   required from here
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:850:20: error: conversion from ‘const Trouble’ to ‘long long int’ is ambiguous
       sizeof(Helper(ImplicitlyConvertible::MakeFrom())) == 1;
             ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/gdpr1/Code/sandbox/mocking/Bar.h:7:0,
                 from /home/gdpr1/Code/sandbox/mocking/FooTest.cpp:3:
/home/gdpr1/Code/sandbox/mocking/Foo.h:17:5: note: candidate: Trouble::operator int() const
     operator int() const { return value; }
     ^~~~~~~~
/home/gdpr1/Code/sandbox/mocking/Foo.h:16:5: note: candidate: Trouble::operator short int() const
     operator short() const { return value; }
     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:58:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h:46,
                 from /cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:46,
                 from /cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:58,
                 from /home/gdpr1/Code/sandbox/mocking/FooTest.cpp:1:
/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:833:15: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘static char testing::internal::ImplicitlyConvertible<From, To>::Helper(To) [with From = const Trouble&; To = long long int]’
   static char Helper(To);
               ^~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tests.dir/build.make:87: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/FooTest.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/tests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:95: all] Error 2
```

This is a small file to show the issue:

main.cpp

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class Special
{
private:
    char value;

public:
    Special(char v) : value(v) {}

    operator short() const { return value; }
    operator int() const { return value; }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() {};
    virtual Foo& foo() = 0;
    virtual Special getVariant() = 0;
};

class MockFoo : public Foo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(foo, Foo&());
    MOCK_METHOD0(getVariant, Special());
};

TEST(FooTest, callFoo)
{
    MockFoo myFoo;
    ::testing::DefaultValue<Foo&>::Set(myFoo);

    EXPECT_CALL(myFoo, foo()).Times(1);
    myFoo.foo();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I’m using Cygwin (CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW) on a Windows 7 machine, gcc version is 6.4.0 and I use C++98. My cmake file is:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6)
project (httpproperpty)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/bin)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
include_directories("/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googletest/include")
include_directories("/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/include")

LINK_DIRECTORIES("/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("/cygdrive/c/GPDR1/Code/googletest/googlemock/gtest/")

# file(GLOB Source_files "*.cpp")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)

add_executable(tests "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries (tests gtest gmock)

enable_testing()

add_test(NAME mytests
         COMMAND tests)
```

I have searched, but could not find any solutions are answers. Any ideas on how to solve this? I can remove the const from the user-defined conversion methods, but I doubt this is a proper solutions. Regardless, in my actual code I can't as easily change the methods.

So far the only solution is to stub instead of mock the method which returns this object (`getVariant`), but that's not a great solution in the long rung.

Comment: There seems to be conversions to `int` and `short`, but the Helper wants a `long long int`. So which conversion is the compiler supposed to use?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly:  

Because a `long long int` is expected and there exist two user-defined conversions which can be turned into a `long long int` via the second standard conversion sequence, he (correctly) complains about ambiguity.  

Adding a user-defined conversion for `long long int` does help alleviate the problem, but I guess I am uncertain if this is the correct way to go...

Comment: I don't know either, as it depends on what you are supposed to be testing. But you are correct that `short` and `int` are both convertible to `long long`, and there is no preference for either one.

Comment: Well in the original `Special` class the issue is with converison to `const void *` as there are two user-defined conversions there who return pointers `const char *` and `const unsigned char *` respectively. I will talk to the owner of the code about adding `operator const void*() const { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the above example is to add a user-defined conversion to convert to `long long int`:

`operator long long int() const { return value; }`

to the `Special` class

```
class Special
{
private:
    char value;

public:
    Special(char v) : value(v) {}

    operator short() const { return value; }
    operator int() const { return value; }
    operator long long int() const { return value; }
};
```

This resolves the ambiguity. The ambiguity is there because the `Helper` class wants to convert it to `long long int` and the compiler can choose to either convert it to `short` or `int`, both of which can be converted to `long long int`.